# Pass docker secret to environment variables

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I would like to pass a connection string as environment variable with user/pass from docker secrets, something like this:

```
version: '3.6'

secrets:
  Mongo__UserName:
    external: true
  Mongo__Password:
    external: true

mongodb:
    image: mongo:6.0.2
    ports:
      - '5000:27017'

client:
    image: xxxxx.com/client:latest
    environment:
      - Mongo__ConnectionString=mongodb://${Mongo__UserName}:${Mongo__Password}@mongodb:27017/dbName
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    secrets:
      - Mongo__UserName
      - Mongo__Password
```

Using `${}` I get the error:

`The connection string 'mongodb://<hidden>@mongodb:27017/dbName' is not valid`

Without `${}` I get the error:

`Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1`

If I hardcode the `username:password` it works.

Comment: I think you need quotes around your URL since it contains colons. Also, the double underscore may be evaluating `Mongo__UserName` as `Mongo:UserName` for the real env name. Consider echoing/print all the vars from your app before connecting to ensure that it's actually reading the vars correctly - `Mongo__UserName`, `Mongo__Password`, `Mongo__ConnectionString`

Comment: @aneroid Thanks, in my application I'm reading as `Mongo:UserName` so using double underscore is correct. All the vars are correct in docker secrets.